Climbing only works with ApplyRootMotion, but this interferes with swiping to jump or slide
I am making a mobile game. To make the player character jump or slide on the ground, I must swipe up or down with the mouse on my computer.
I also want my character to climb a wall. The solution I found is to use ApplyRootMotion.
Unfortunately, when it is activated, swiping with the mouse doesn't work correctly. Swiping up and down doesn't give any result. Swiping left or right only works after trying multiple times.
When ApplyRootMotion is disabled, everything works fine, but I can't implement Climbing. I need help to implement this Climbing.
This is the InputManager script:
public static MobileInput Instance {get; set;}
private const float DEADZONE = 100.0f;
private float timer;

private bool tap, longPress, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeDown;
private Vector2 swipeDelta, startTouch;
// Start is called before the first frame update

public bool Tap { get { return tap; } }
public bool LongPress { get { return longPress; } }
public bool SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
public bool SwipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
public bool SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
public bool SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }
public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
public Vector2 StartTouch { get { return startTouch; } }

private void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;
}

private void Update()
{
    //Reseting all the booleans
    tap = swipeLeft = swipeRight = swipeUp = swipeDown = false;

    //Let's check for Inputs
    #region Standalone Inputs

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // *if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) is to block interaction under the screen

        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
         return;

        tap = true;
        startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        // *if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) is to block interaction under the screen
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
         return;

        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer >= 1f)   //See if 1 can be reduced to 0.8 or 0.5 later
        {
            longPress = true;
            Debug.Log("Long press");
            timer = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            longPress = false;
        }
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) == false)
    {
        timer = 0;
        longPress = false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Mobile Inputs
    if (Input.touches.Length != 0)
    {
        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            // *if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) is to block interaction under the screen
            
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
                return;

            tap = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
        {
            longPress = false;
            startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        }

        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                if (timer >= 1.5f)   //See if 1 can be reduced to 0.8 or 0.5 later
                {
                    longPress = true;
                    timer = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    longPress = false;
                    // Check below in SwipeDelta calculation
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    //Calculate distance
    swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    if (startTouch != Vector2.zero)
    {
        //Let's check with mobile
        if (Input.touches.Length != 0)
        {
            swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
        }
        //Let's check with standalone
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
        }
    }

    //Let's check if we are beyond the dead zone
    if (swipeDelta.magnitude > DEADZONE)
    {
        //This is a confirmed swipe
        float x = swipeDelta.x;
        float y = swipeDelta.y;

        if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
        {
            //Left or Right
            if (x < 0)
                swipeLeft = true;
            else
                swipeRight = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Up and Down
            if (y < 0)
                swipeDown = true;
            // longPress = false; Check this one
            else
                swipeUp = true;
            // longPress = false;
        }

        startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
    }
}


Are you finding that swipes are not detected by this InputManager class when ApplyRootMotion is enabled? Or are they detected (the appropriate boolean gets set to true), but the character does not animate right? If it's the latter, we'll need to see how you set up the animations, animator controller graph, and your animation code. To help get answers faster, you might want to create a small test project with a simplified example, just two swipes / two animations. This can cut down on the amount of code/setup you need to show to reproduce the issue, leaving fewer places for a bug to hide.

The issue was related to ground check. 
In my script, SwipeUp can make Player jump only when it's grounded. I don't know how but ApplyRootMotion makes my character not fully interact with ground. I was using characterController.isgrounded to check if my character is on the ground and it did not work well. So I created a ground check method with overlapSphere and I adjusted characterController Skin Width to 0.02. It works now.
